# how to install universal app on Pefecto Mobile CQlab devices

Tags: mobile, universal

It said that Perfecto supports all kind of platforms, devices. However I can only find guideline for installing iOS and android apps. Does anyone know how to install Windows universal app on the devices in Perfecto CQlab

Answer (score 1):

Perfecto is releasing support for Windows 10 Win Apps (Universal) starting in version 8.5, the support is for Windows 10 PC like OS on Surface Pro devices, e.g. the Surface Pro 3 and Pro 4.

Installing the WinApp is done the same way as iOS and Android app. Win 10 automation is done using MS WinAppDriver Appium Server for Windows 10

Comment: Have you got any links that might give Jindovn Cuong a little more information, if needed?

Comment: MS WinAppDriver info can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/, Perfecto fully supports WinAppDriver.